# Firebase Database Never Saves Configuration

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a weird issue, and since I haven't seen anyone asking about it I feel like there is something very simple I'm missing. I've been trying to get my Firebase Real-time database configuration to save, but every time I switch to a different tab (database, authentication, hosting, etc) or leave the console it erases and I get booted back to the "select a database" screen. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a picture of what it looks like once I re-select Real-time Database:

[image]

Comment: what are ur database rules?

Comment: It doesn't matter because when I leave the database tab they get erased. That's my problem. I can save them, simulate, do whatever, but as soon as I leave the database tab I need to reconfigure from scratch

Answer (score 0):

In order for a database to "stick" you actually have to put data into it. So try and push something to it and see if you still run into this issue.